# OpenCSV problem using HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy with foreign keys

Tags: java, opencsv

I'm using OpenCSV 5.0 to parse my csv with `HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy`. It works well and I had no problems using primitive data types like String, int, boolean etc.

Because somebody asked for it. The `file` is part of the requestParams of the method.

```
@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
```

But now I have an attribute thats object of another class.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "article$ean", referencedColumnName = "ean")
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Article article$ean;
```

When CsvToBean is parsing the elements is throws an error for every element:

```
Konvertierung von 010000 in de.iis.databaseHub.entity.Article fehlgeschlagen.
```

Translated in English:

```
Conversion from 010000 to de.iis.databaseHub.entity.Article failed.
```

My entity (shortened) looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Data //lombok annotation
public class Transaction implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long transactionId;

    @Size(max = 30)
    private String timestamp;

    private int receiptNo;

    private int receiptPosNo; // (e.g. 1-x then again 1-y)

    @JoinColumn(name = "article$ean", referencedColumnName = "ean")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Article article$ean;
}
```

My parser works like this. `entry.getKey()` sets the entity class and `entry.getValue()` sets the mapping

```
    List<Transaction> transaction = new ArrayList<>();

    HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy strategy = new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy();
    strategy.setType(entry.getKey());
    strategy.setColumnMapping(entry.getValue());

    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream());
    CSVParser parser = new CSVParserBuilder().withFieldAsNull(CSVReaderNullFieldIndicator.EMPTY_SEPARATORS)
            .withSeparator(delimiter).withIgnoreQuotations(false).build();
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(reader).withSkipLines(0).withCSVParser(parser).build();

    CsvToBean<?> csvToBean = new CsvToBean<>();

    csvToBean.setThrowExceptions(false);
    csvToBean.setMappingStrategy(strategy);
    csvToBean.setCsvReader(csvReader);

    if (entry.getKey().equals(Transaction.class)) {
        transaction.addAll((Collection<? extends Transaction>) csvToBean.parse());
        transaction.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
    }
```

How am I possible to handle this?

Comment: Hi CptDayDreamer can you provide the declaration of the attribute "file" (called by file.getInputStream() method)

Comment: @bdzzaid added the declaration of the file